# Is it possible to send network request by loop in Cypress test

Tags: javascript, typescript, automation, graphql, cypress

I know there is same official limitation to send network request by loop in Cypress,
but probably there is some unofficial way to do it.

The use case is to send some `cy.request()` and wrap in in `for()` or `while()` loop and pass different values in the header everytime from some array or directly from the database and then to manipulate on the result by some assert.

e.g.

```
let query = 'query bla bla bla'
let projectId = some value from array or db';
let result;

describe('Tests', () => {
  it('send graphql request to endpoint', () => {
    for(let i = 0; 0 > 3; i++) {
    cy.request({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://www.blabla.con/api2',
      body: {
        'operationName': 'bla bla',
        'variables': {
          'campaignProjectId': null,
          'ids': [ { 'type': 'project', 'id': projectId } ],
          'userData': null,
        },
        query,
      },
      headers: {
        'accept': '*/*',
        'content-type': 'application/json',
      },
    }).then((response: any) => {
    // placeholder for assert - will compare between the results
      expect(JSON.stringify(response.body.data).is.equal(JSON.stringify(result);
    });
};
});
```

In the code above, it's just looping without to send the request, seems like a recursive issue or something else.

Comment: There should be nothing wrong with looping through a data set and firing off multiple requests. Is there a sequence needed (i.e 2nd one only after first one finishes)?

Comment: If I wrapping this request with for loop it skips on the request and just looping

Comment: Yes, see recursive answer below - it's a bit rough but may give you the pattern.

Comment: Let me revise that - to make the for-loop work you need to pass in the done method like this `it('send graphql request to endpoint', (done) => {` and call it after the last `expect(JSON.stringify...` line.

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work, it's reached the timeout and didn't execute the request. - 
`Timed out after 15000ms. The done() callback was never invoked!`

Comment: The timeout will need to be adjusted and you will have to check each of the response times. Recursion is (arguably) better, which is why I posted that answer.

Comment: I also notice the comment "will compare between the results" - that's also easier with recursion because the 2nd call is fired within the response of the first call, so you can pass results along.

Comment: I've increase the timeout and still nothing invoke.
can you please send some example how to wrap network request by a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at @ArtjomProzorov question [Cy requests retries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72684968/cy-requests-retries).

The same approach can work with some mods. Maybe set the attempts limit to the total number of data items to send, and return instead of throwing an error.

```js
const data = [...]

function req (attempts = 0) {

  if (attempts === data.length) return // finished the data set

  const dataset = data[attempts]

  cy.request(...)              // format request from dataset
    .then((resp) => {

      // handle response

      cy.wait(300)      // 300 ms delay so as not to slam the server
      req(++attempts)
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer was good enough for my use case and really help